# Set parent height relative to child height.

Tags: html, css, height

In the code below, `B1` contains an image and `B2` includes an iframe.

The height of `B` and `container` is equal to the height of `B1`, but `B2` is overflowing the container, which I don't want. How do I fix this?

```
<div id="container">
    </div>
    <div id="B">
        <div id="B1">
             <img src="example.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="B2">
             <iframe src="example.htm">
                   Your browser doesn't support iframes.
             </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `.B { width: auto; }`

Comment: There is a syntax error. The container is wrongly closed.

Comment: why is `container` closed without covering `B` class though you  mentioned that in your explanation???

Comment: @NoobEditor oh container contain other class too :) i miss it

Comment: @user2637015 : mmmm....so we still have some problem or you got it solved???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give `container` value `display:inline-block`

and `B2`, `overflow:auto`

That should help!!

**EDIT**

Assuming you container is closed incorrectly, this should be your html markup :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="B">
        <div id="B1">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="B2">
            <iframe src=""></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and **CSS**

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#B {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#B1,#B2,iframe,img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto; /*to mainatin height as per requirement */
}
```

[**basic demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ca4VA/)